# Excel "Application or Object Defined Error" No Explanation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, bloomberg

I have built a spreadsheet which simply pulls data on securities from Bloomberg.

Whenever I try to recalucate Excell throws me an error Mesage:

"Applicatoin or Object Deffiened Error"

But It provides me with no more explanation than that!

How can I find source of this error?
Also if there are common sources of this error what are they?

NOTES:

-Spreadsheet does not use VBA, but it was created using it

-At the time of creation there was no errors,they started only at first Recalcuation of the Spreadsheet

-There are 20 tabs with hunderds of rows in each, thu I prefer to figure it out algorythmicaly if the problem comes from formulas( I essentially have thousads of formulas)

Example Formula:
`IFERROR(ROUND(BDS(CUSIP,"COLLATERAL_QUERY_RESULT_HIST","COLLATERAL_QUERY_OVERRIDE","{'operation':'predefined','parameters':{'field':'"&A3&"'}}","Dir=H","cols=85;rows=2","Fill=-"),0),"-")`

Comment: **Post your Bloomberg formulas.**

Comment: BDS returns an array - are you sure your formula works?

Comment: Can you show us the code behind `Spreadsheet does not use VBA, but it was created using it`?

Comment: @Thinkingcap I'm affraid that I dont'have access tha toth at code, at the moment.. but I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dialog box pops up when an error is thrown by a COM object. I'll bet the Bloomberg Add-In is defined as a COM object, and your query is doing something that it doesn't like. If you have access to Bloomberg's support service (or have a friend who does) you can submit this as a bug.

You can confirm that by doing the call to BDS (or whatever) in VBA. It still won't work, but you might be able to wrap it in an `On Error` block and then look at `Err.Number` to get some more information.

Comment: Yeah you're right I copied formulas wihtin this spreadsheet and I delegated issure to Bloomberg.

Thanks